# Query grouping by non-fixed time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to group by moving, non-fixed, time intervals.
That is, I have some events having a start and an end, and I'd like to count how many events where occurring at the same time.

I have a table like this

```
       start         |          end           |   desc
-----------------------------------------------------------
'2018-03-29 13:36:52'|'2018-03-29 13:37:52+02'|'Alarm_821'
'2018-03-29 13:39:52'|'2018-03-29 13:41:52+02'|'Alarm_821'
'2018-03-29 15:44:15'|'2018-03-29 15:50:16+02'|'Alarm_819'
'2018-03-29 15:44:15'|'2018-03-29 15:51:16+02'|'Alarm_817'
'2018-03-29 16:08:18'|'2018-03-29 16:10:19+02'|'Alarm_418'
'2018-03-29 16:08:18'|'2018-03-29 16:10:19+02'|'Alarm_465'
'2018-03-29 16:11:19'|'2018-03-29 16:15:19+02'|'Alarm_418'
```

And I'd like to obtain this result:

```
           start         |          end     |     count
-----------------------------------------------------------
'2018-03-29 13:36:52'|'2018-03-29 13:37:52+02'|     1
'2018-03-29 13:39:52'|'2018-03-29 13:41:52+02'|     1
'2018-03-29 15:44:15'|'2018-03-29 15:50:16+02'|     2
'2018-03-29 15:50:16'|'2018-03-29 15:51:16+02'|     1       <<== here start refers to the end of the first event ending when both of them started
'2018-03-29 16:08:18'|'2018-03-29 16:10:19+02'|     2
'2018-03-29 16:11:19'|'2018-03-29 16:15:19+02'|     1
```

I'm actually not sure that this can be done by only using SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on a UNION of all times in the table. It creates adjacent pairs from this list and then it searches of interval overlaps.

```
select t.st, t.en, count(*)
from
(
  select lag(tm) over (order by tm) st, tm en
  from
  (
    select "start" tm from data 
    union
    select "end" tm from data
  ) r
) t
join data on t.st < data."end" and t.en > data."start"
group by t.st, t.en
order by t.st
```

[DBFiddle DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4af03e723bb0edb4f37794389f4be81d)

Comment: what if I wanted to insert the 0 counts in between?

Comment: I mean, if I have an interval from 16:03 to 17:03 and another from 18:45 to 19:00, I'd like to have a row from 17:03 to 18:45 with count 0

Comment: I managed to obtain it like this, but it's quite cumbersome https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aecbbd08b8351682f8823d70882f21a5

Comment: @balsick and what about the left join? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=45e1d87a8d98cf7ce21ce379433e50ea

Comment: thanks, your query looks nicer and the result looks more reliable